# Unable to save the value against the column whose size is 1024 and that that field contains the 1008 characters

Tags: sql

I have column whose size is 1024 and for this field I tried to save the value whose charactres count in 1008 but still I am unable to save this value against this column.

[image]

I got error like **Provided value is too large for field PickupInstruction. Max length allowed is 1,024.**

Also I have confirmed chars count at *https://www.charactercountonline.com/* and it's 1008.

Please provide solution or help me to undersand what is the issue.

Comment: 1008 characters could take more than 1008 _bytes_.

Comment: Yep - your field is 1024 BYTEs long, not 1024 CHARS long.

Answer (score 0):

Your column stores 1024 Bytes not characters - in a multibyte character set like UTF-8 you might be able to store fewer characters...
Either increase the size of the column or specify to store 1024 chars like `ALTER TABLE ... VARCHAR2(1024 CHAR)` - default is to use bytes.

Comment: Also I tried your solution i.e. chnaged column datatype but still gettting the same error.

Comment: Depends on the characters you want to insert - in case of UTF characters where a `char` uses up to 4 Bytes the 1024 Bytes can hold 256 Chars (worst case)

Comment: Can you query the all_tab_columns for the char_used, char_lenght and the data_type?